# iOS純正の「ファイル」アプリ内のデータを外部のアプリから削除する方法

Tags: swift, ios, filesystems

iOS純正の「ファイル」アプリ内に格納したデータを任意の外部アプリから間接的に（ファイルアプリを開かず）消すことって出来るんでしょうか？という質問になります。ご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、助言いただけますと幸いです。

【参考】
一般的にiOSはアプリ間連携はシビアなので、実施不可ではと考えていたのですが、参考情報としてサードパーティ製のファイルアプリ（例えば[Readdle社のdocuments](https://readdle.com/ja/documents)）からデータを削除すると、iOS純正のファイルアプリからもデータが削除される事象を確認しており、もしかすると実現可能なのではと考えております。

Answer (score 3):

Document-based appですね。

https://developer.apple.com/jp/document-based-apps/

Document-based appを作ってUIDocumentBrowserControllerを使うとFile.appと同等のアプリケーションが実現できます。UIDocumentBrowserControllerを使うのでプログラムから完全に自由にアクセスできるわけではありません。

ちなみに、File.appも同様ですが、扱えるファイルはアプリがDocument Directoryを公開しているものだけです。